# Redmine Container shuts down instantly

Tags: docker, redmine

For some reason, my redmine container stays up 2 sec and then shuts down.

I have followed the steps on the [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine):

```
docker network create --driver bridge redmine_network

docker run -d --name postgres --network redmine_network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -e POSTGRES_USER=redmine postgres

docker run -d --name redmine --network redmine_network -e REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES=some-postgres -e REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=redmine -e REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=secret redmine
```

But the image does not stay up for some reason, no logs no nothing, am I the only one?